# How to Resolve the TypeNotPresentException error in pom.xml while creating a spring boot project

Tags: java, maven, spring-boot

I am new to spring boot and trying to create a simple spring boot application. When I create a maven project and add the parent in the pom file, I get below error

```
CoreException: Could not get the value for parameter compilerId for plugin execution default-compile: TypeNotPresentException: Type org.apache.maven.plugin.compiler.CompilerMojo not present: UnsupportedClassVersionError: org/apache/maven/plugin/compiler/CompilerMojo : Unsupported major.minor version 51.0   pom.xml /spring-boot-example    line 14 Maven Project Build Lifecycle Mapping Problem
```

Please can someone guide me if any solution.
Updating the pom file below.

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>com.abc.springbootexample</groupId>
  <artifactId>spring-boot-example</artifactId>
  <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <packaging>jar</packaging>
  <name>spring-boot-example</name>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.0.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath/>
    </parent>
  <properties>
    <java.version>1.8</java.version>
  </properties>
  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>
</project>
```

Comment: It will be good if you add your pom file here

Comment: updated the pom file

Comment: If you are familiar with Maven, directly go into this location https://start.spring.io/ and download base project.

Comment: yes I created the base project in start.spring.io then imported it as an existing maven project. But getting this issue